# Numpy: Create a mask array to select rectangle

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, mask

Is there a way to generate an array, masking a rectangular area, without the need to initialize an empty array first?

```
mask = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=bool)
mask[10/2:,10/2:] = True
```

Im looking for an numpy expression that would replace these two lines and generate `mask`

Answer (score 2):

If you really, really want to have a one-liner, this is a possible way. But I'd say your original code is cleaner, clearer, and overall better...

```
>>> np.logical_and.outer(np.arange(10) >= 5, np.arange(6) >= 3)
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

That can be done in one line:

```
mask = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: (i >= 5) * (j >= 5), (10, 10), dtype=int)
```

but this turns out to be quite a bit slower than the original implementation. (It creates two arrays holding row and column indices).

You can use `np.empty` if you don't want to initialize the array and set the values manually. In this specific case, however, you might be better off using `np.zeros` or `np.ones` and flip the values for whichever is the smallest number of entries that you need to update.